Showing integrability of f+g and additivity of the Darboux integral
I am currently working on the following question from Measure, Integration & Real Analysis by Sheldon Axler:

Suppose $f,g:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ are Riemann (Darboux) integrable on $[a,b]$. Prove that $f+g$ is integrable on $[a,b]$, and
$\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}(f+g)=\int_{a}^{b}f+\int_{a}^{b}g$

My attempt looks like this:
Let $\varepsilon \in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ be given. Since $f$ and $g$ are integrable, we can find partitions $P_\varepsilon$ and $P_\varepsilon'$ of $[a,b]$, such that:
$\displaystyle U(f,P_\varepsilon)-L(f,P_{\varepsilon})<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$
$\displaystyle U(g,P_\varepsilon')-L(g,P_{\varepsilon}')<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$
Consider the partition $P=P_\varepsilon\cup P_\varepsilon'$. Since $P$ is a refinement of $P_\varepsilon$ and $P_\varepsilon'$, it follows that $U(f,P_\varepsilon)\ge U(f,P)$ and $L(f,P)\ge L(f,P_\varepsilon)$. This means that:
$\displaystyle U(f,P)-L(f,P)\le U(f,P_\varepsilon)-L(f,P_\varepsilon )<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\implies U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$
The same reasoning applies to $g$. This means that:
$\displaystyle U(f,P)-L(f,P)+(U(g,P)-L(g,P)) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$
If we rearrange the terms slightly, we get:
$\displaystyle U(f,P)+U(g,P)-(L(f,P)+L(g,P))<\varepsilon$
The upper and lower sums can be written together, i.e. $U(f,P)+U(g,P) = U(f+g, P)$ and $L(f,P)+L(g,P)=L(f+g,P)$.
This finally gives us:
$\displaystyle U(f+g,P)-L(f+g,P)<\varepsilon$ $\blacksquare$
What I hope I have proven now is that given that $f,g$ are integrable, for all $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$, such that $U(f+g,P)-L(f+g,P)<\varepsilon$. Have I succeded in proving this or have I made mistakes somewhere?

And as for the additivity, I had something like this in mind (only considering the upper sum since the upper sum is equal to the lower sum):
$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b}\left(f+g\right)= \inf\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i-x_{i-1}\right)\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}\left(f+g\right)=\inf\sum_{i=1}^{n}[\left(x_i-x_{i-1}\right)\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}f+\left(x_i-x_{i-1}\right)\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}g]=\inf\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i-x_{i-1}\right)\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}f+\inf\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(x_i-x_{i-1}\right)\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]}g=U\left(f\right)+U\left(g\right)=\int_{a}^{b}f+\int_{a}^{b}g$

Your proof is quite good. It proves $f+g$ is integrable in the usual, most straightforward way.
For additivity, your idea does work, or you might continue with what you've already shown.
Since the three functions are integrable,
$$ \begin{align*} L(f,P) \leq \int_a^b f \leq U(f,P) &&\implies&& 0 \leq \int_a^b f - L(f,P) < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
L(g,P) \leq \int_a^b g \leq U(g,P) &&\implies&& 0 \leq \int_a^b g - L(g,P) < \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
L(f+g) \leq \int_a^b (f+g) \leq U(f+g) &&\implies&& 0 \leq \int_a^b (f+g) - L(f+g,P) < \epsilon
\end{align*} $$
$$ \left| \int_a^b(f+g) - \int_a^b f - \int_a^b g\,\right| < \epsilon + \frac \epsilon 2 + \frac \epsilon 2 = 2\epsilon $$
Since such a $P$ exists for any positive $\epsilon$, this shows that
$$ \int_a^b (f+g) = \int_a^b f + \int_a^b g $$
